# How can I improvise a kids double bunker bed?

Tags: bedroom

I have a small bedroom and two single beds on ensemble. I want to fit them in the corner in an L shape but on top of each other. This means part of one bed will go underneath the other one. My local hardware shop said i need very strong platform to support the top bed. I dont have the skills but a thought came to me that I can use a dinning table as the platform. Its strong and will not collapse. Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: If you don't have building skills, then I would suggest buying a [loft bed](http://www.amazon.com/Loft-Bed-Frames-Headboards-Furniture/b?ie=UTF8&node=3733181) that's designed for this purpose. But in that case, this question wouldn't be very DIY.

Comment: Dining room tables are made for plates and food, not people!

Comment: As BMitch says very politely, this may not be a good DIY starter project if you lack skills.  No matter how you do it, one bed will be hanging, in part or whole, over one of your friends or family.  If it fails, its a risk of serious injury. Buy a set of beds or prefab, or get someone with significant experience to do the project.

Comment: Ya - Get a carpenter in to do it for you privatley, he will take a few bux and make a sturdy platform for you. You don't want to hurt your kids do you? They gonna be jumping and handing off those beds.. I did when I was 8... and I still would today ;-)

Comment: rent the movie "Step Brothers", real good design tips in there.

Answer (score 3):

Kids being kids this is a bad idea. Without any means of locking the bed on the table it will slide off and someone will get hurt. One lower cost option is to check craigslist and see if someone needs to swap some bunk beds for regular twins. I admit it would be a long shot but eventually someones kids has grow out of them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite follow how a dining room table would fit in to this equation. Typically beds can be turned into bunk beds by fastening the bestposts together. Whether your beds can handle that structurally, I don't know.

I have done the L-bed thing with a pair of Ikea beds, though. Maybe this gives you some ideas:

[image]

I got a whole bunch of 2x2s and Simpson L and U brackets, along with a saw, screws and bolts.